# process to install ssl on linux machine

Tags: ssl, iphone

Please provide me a way to install ssl certificate on linux machine. Alternatively please do provide me process to install .p12 or .cer file on linux machine.

Is it necessary to install the ssl certificate on the machine(fedora linux), which is being used to connect to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com for iphone push

Answer (score 3):

Installing a certificate / key on a linux machine is as simple as copying the file to the server.  Most distributions have a standard location for storing the certificates and/or keys.  The harder problem is configuring your application to look in the correct directory.

What application will need to use this certificate?  Are you installing a root certificate to validate the server cert?  Or are you installing a certificate and key so you can serve information over SSL?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it would be great if you could give me some pointers as to which location in Fedora, the files would be stored. 

I am trying to install a certificate and key , to serve info over SSL.

Comment: Standard location on most linuxes is /etc/ssl, however it doesn't matter as services need to individually be pointed at the certificate and key.

Comment: As LapTop006 points out, it doesn't really matter *where* you install them, as long as you point Apache (or whatever service you're using) to the correct certificate and key.  

I dont' have ready access to a Fedora box, but the common locations are `/etc/ssl/certs/` for the certificate and `/etc/ssl/private` for the key.  On RedHat, though, it appears to be `/etc/pki/tls/{certs,private}`.  I'm not sure which approach Fedora uses.